# Why error occurs when XSLT TBB get XML from a package?

Tags: 2013-sp1, xslt

I'm making a component template by using XSLT TBBs.
The template contains 1 C# TBB and 2 XSLT TBBS(XSLT1 and XSLT2). 
What my template doing is following.

1. C# TBB generate XML and push it to package
2. XSLT1 TBB get the XML from package, and push transformed XML to
   package.
3. XSLT2 TBB get the XML(transformed by XSLT1) from package, and push
   transformed XML to package.

But following error occurs on XSLT2.

**There Is No Unicode Byte Order Mark. Cannot Switch to Unicode.**

I noticed that encoding of XML item pushed by XSLT1 is "utf-16" regardless of XSLT1 specifies encoding="utf-8" on xsl:output element.
How can I use XSLT TBB by this way?

My source codes are following:

**C# TBB**

```
 class TestXMLTBB:TemplateBase
    {
          public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
          {
              string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root><element>value</element></root>";
              package.PushItem("TestXML1", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Xml, xml));
          }
    }
```

**XSLT1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?XsltMediator inputItemName="TestXML1" outPutItemName="TestXML2"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?XsltMediator inputItemName="TestXML2" outPutItemName="TestXML3"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I revised C#, but same error occurs. Revised source code is following.

```
  class TestXMLTBB:TemplateBase
    {
          public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
          {
             MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
             XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
             XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false))
             {
                 Indentation = 4,
                 Formatting = Formatting.Indented
             };

            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");
            writer.WriteStartElement("element");
            writer.WriteValue("value");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            package.PushItem("TestXML1", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Xml, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray())));
          }
    }
```

Regards,

Comment: It would appear the problem occurs in the XSLT mediator and not in your code; are you using the XSLT mediator or are you using custom C# code to perform the XSLT transform and store the result? If so please list that code as well...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would normally create a XML object in the package:

```
package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, package.CreateStringItem
                (ContentType.Xml, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray())));
```

And I would normally use a `MemoryStream` and `XmlTextWriter` (link to full example below). This would ensure that not only the XML document states it is UTF-8, it actually *really* is UTF-8.

As you noticed, by default Tridion will use UTF-16.

Code sample available in [github](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/SDL-Tridion-Template-Tools/blob/master/Tridion%20Standard%20Templates/TridionTemplates/GetSiteNavigationXml-SG.cs) from my [Tridion Standard Templates](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/SDL-Tridion-Template-Tools/tree/master/Tridion%20Standard%20Templates) share.

Comment: I reviced source code, but same error occured. XSLT1 is no problem, but XSLT2 cause the error.XSLT2 is get XML that is pushed by XSLT1 to package. Is this operation possible? I add reviced source code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is because the XML declaration claims that the encoding is `UTF-16`, but the actual encoding is not.
`XslCompiledTransform`(which is used internally) has a tendency to put such an `UTF-16` XML declaration in the output and ignore the encoding specified in the `xsl:output element`.

Can you try what happens if you put `omit-xml-declaration="true"` on the `xsl:output` element of XSLT1 (that should suppress the XML declaration altogether and the default XML encoding is `UTF-8`).

Comment: I added omit-xml-declaration="yes" to XSLT1, then XML Declaration disappered, and no error occured. And XSLT2 is applied to the XML, so I can achieve my purpose by this way.

Comment: This helped me too! I had the same issue and adding omit-xml-declaration=yes to the first XSLT TBB it fixed the error. I would mark this as the answer to this question.